# what should i do to make this error redundunt

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm having difficulty requesting permission for location access in my Kotlin class file. Despite following the steps provided in the course I'm enrolled in, I'm encountering an error. Specifically, when attempting to access fine location, the error arises

[how can i solve this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhCky.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try `Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` and make sure you imported `android.Manifest`.